# Reading the Set-Cookie instructions in an HTTP Response header

Tags: php, http, cookies

Is there any standard means in PHP to read the `Set-Cookie` instructions in an HTTP Response header, without manually parsing it?

More specifically, I want to read the value of the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie returned by an ASP.NET Web Service I am consuming.

---

**EDIT:**

I am consuming the Web Service using PHP's native `SoapClient` class. I can use the `__getLastResponseHeaders()` method to retrieve the whole of the HTTP response header returned by the Web Service:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ku501l55o300ik3sa2gu3vzj; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 11 Jan 2011 23:34:02 GMT
Content-Length: 368
```

But I want to extract the value of the `ASP.NET_SessionID` cookie:

```
ku501l55o300ik3sa2gu3vzj
```

And, of course, I don't want to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the cookies returned via SOAP client by using:

```
var_dump($client->_cookies);

echo "cookie is ".$client->_cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"][0];
```

Comment: This works fine. But i can't find anything in the php documentation. Where you've found this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$_COOKIE['ASP.NET_SessionId'];
```

Or this:

```
$cookies = getCookies();
$sessionId = $cookies['ASP.NET_SessionId'];
```

Not sure if the last part will work correctly - if it does not, you could try:

```
print_r($cookies);
```

to see if it even returns anything.

Comment: No, it does not work. Me thinks `$_COOKIE` only contains cookies read from the user, not cookies returned by a Web Service.

Comment: @Eduardo León When is PHP *not* on the server side?

Comment: As long as the cookie domain and path are set correctly when the cookie is placed, it should be readable.

Comment: @alex: PHP is on the server side from the point of view of the user, but on the client side from the point of view of the Web Service I am consuming.

Comment: From what I can tell, the SoapClient class has a getCookies() method in it. So if you can call that method, you should be able to get the cookies.  Check the edited answer.

Comment: PHP's native `SoapClient` doesn't have a `getCookies()` method, but nuSOAP's `SoapClient` does. I'm going to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Ah...I've never used PHP's soapclient before.  The documentation I was looking at was not clear, but it was probably for a different SOAP client.